# get all user name from all documents in Firestore flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

long story short that I need to get a List< title > of all todos, but now I just have a List< Todo >, so how can I return this List？

get a Stream<List>

```
  static Stream<List<Todo>> readTodos() => FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('todo')
      .orderBy(TodoField.createdTime, descending: true)
      .snapshots()
      .transform(Utils.transformer(Todo.fromJson));
```

and then with StreamBuilder I am able to get a List, but for a method I just need all name of these todos, so I hope in the end it will look like this:

```
todoTitle: [
        'eat',
        'drink',
        'run',
      ]
```

so what I can do? Thanks a lot!

**Update**
I dont know if the following is a solution, but it does not work yet:

```
final provider = Provider.of<TodosProvider>(context);
final todos = provider.todos;
List<String> userTitle = todos.map['Todo'].where((todo) => todo['title'] != null).map((value) => value['title']).toList();
```

and then i got an error from map['Todo'], the error is (`The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Iterable<T> Function<T>(T Function(Todo))'.`), please help T T thanks!

[image: structure of todos]

Comment: It's really hard to say much here without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and probably a screenshot of the document structure you are using.

Comment: Hi Frank, good to see you here again, I update my question, sry im in Germany and now in deep night I cant think clearly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to get some part of the `Todo` class (in this case the `title`) You can use the `Stream.map` method:

```
    static Stream<List<String>> readTodoTitles() => FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('todo')
      .orderBy(TodoField.createdTime, descending: true)
      .snapshots()
      .transform(Utils.transformer(Todo.fromJson))
      .map<String>((list) => 
        list.map((element) => element.title,
      ).toList());
```

Comment: Hi h8moss, thanks a lot for your help, but I follow ur answer and get an error, sorry to take your time but could you plz tell me what I need to do? here is the error (A value of type 'Stream<String>' can't be returned from the method 'readTodoTitles' because it has a return type of 'Stream<List<String>>')

Comment: and if i update ur answer like this (  static Stream<String> readTodoTitles() => FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('todo')
      .orderBy(TodoField.createdTime, descending: true)
      .snapshots()
      .transform(Utils.transformer(Todo.fromJson))
      .map<String>((element) => element.title);) I will get an error from element.title (The getter 'title' isn't defined for the type 'List<Todo>')

Comment: @mattipeterbull I see... I am not sure how to fix this because I have very little information, still, I have updated my answer with a possible new solution, would you mind taking a look at it?

Comment: hi h8moss, thanks a lot for your help and sry for my late reply, I have to work at day.... there is still a error (A value of type 'Stream<String>' can't be returned from the method 'readTodoTitles' because it has a return type of 'Stream<List<String>>'. (Documentation)
The return type 'List<String>' isn't a 'String', as required by the closure's context.), so after several tries, I think i solved my question...hopefully it is correct, plz see my updated answer

Comment: As long as it works, your answer should be the correct one! The problem itself is complicated and perhaps using `.map` is just not the correct approach here. Very happy you were able to find a satisfactory answer

Answer (score 1):

There are two solution(thanks Frank's reply from another stack):

a. create another collection which just contains title, and then get List< Title > easily.

b. fetch all data as current solution, and I use forEach to seperate the value to a List(I still don't know how to do it in map(), plz help me if anyone has any idea):

1. create List< String > to get all titles

   `List< String > titles = [];`
2. get List< Todos > as above displayed in the way of StreamBuilder, and then get all List with provider

```
final provider = Provider.of<TodosProvider>(context);
final todos = provider.todos;
```

3. User forEach to put just `todo.title` in `List< String > titles`

```
getAllTitles(todos){
  todos.forEach((todo) {
    titles.add(todo.title);
  });
}
```

I believe there is a smart way like h8moss showed me, to create another Stream<List> todoTitles, but then I need to listen another stream, I am new to firestore and flutter world, i dont know which one is better or how to do Stream<List> in the right way.. I just put my solution here in case I forget in the future.